# ruby system call cp: missing destination file operand after

Tags: ruby, scripting, terminal

I have something similar to the following in a ruby script:

```
from = "/path/to/script.rb"
to = "/path/to/destination/"
puts "Copying #{from} to #{to}"
system("cp #{from} #{to}")
```

This gives the following output in terminal:

```
copying /path/to/script.rb 
 to /path/to/destination/
cp: missing destination file operand after ‘/path/to/script.rb’
Try 'cp --help' for more information.
```

I have no problem running the following in terminal:

```
cp /path/to/script.rb /path/to/destination
```

Nor within the ruby script:

```
system("cp /path/to/script.rb /path/to/destination")
```

Any advice on how to better troubleshoot my script, or pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does `system('cp', from, to)` work?

Comment: The issue was that I was reading from a file, and not trimming the line breaks. I just edited the output to illustrate.

Comment: You should answer your own question and mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thanks, just updated it. I can accept the answer in 2 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was reading from a file, and not trimming the line breaks. This *should* have been obvious from the terminal output (note the line break and space before 'to').

Changing from:

```
files = []
File.open(file-of-paths).read.each_line do |line|
 files.push(line)
end
```

to the following resolved the issue:

```
files = []
File.open(file-of-paths).read.each_line do |line|
 files.push(line.chomp)
end
```

Comment: You should use [`File.foreach`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/IO.html#method-c-foreach) in order to iterate over lines. It's much more efficient, concise and will close the file after its done with it.